# Animating brooms

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

In Javascript, when I click on the broom, it changes the image src to a gif and changes the ID to "walkingBroom".  This works.

Then, when I click on the broom, it changes the class (this makes it walks across the screen).  This does not work.

I don't know what I doing wrong - can anyone help?  It's like the ID has not been changed.

```
document.getElementById("stillBroom").addEventListener("dblclick", animate);

function animate(){
  document.getElementById("stillBroom").src = "broom.gif";
  document.getElementById("stillBroom").id = "walkingBroom";}


document.getElementById("walkingBroom").addEventListener("click", walk);

function walk(){
  document.getElementById("walkingBroom").className = "broom pattern0 speed1";}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should manage the logic in a variable, like `let currentState="still"`, then on click, change to `currentState="walking"`, and act in consequence. Currently, you are immediately trying to attach a click event to a "walkingBroom" element that doesn't exist (it *will* exist, but later, after you click the broom once). For that matter, your console is very likely saying `Error - Can't read property addEventListener of null` and your script crashes without running. Open your console, it's very useful.

```
let currentState = "still";
broom.addEventListener("dblclick", clickHandler);

const clickHandler = () => {
     switch(currentState) {
          case "still" :
               currentState="walking";
               broom.src="broom.gif";
               break;
          case "walking":
               currentState="flying";
               broom.className = "broom pattern0 speed1";
               break;
     }
}
```